# Java 2d array adding one to element error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

On the program I am working on I have to find a letter pair contained in an unspecified amount of input. If two consecutive English letters that are the same, case-insensitive, are found, then I add one to an element within my 2d array that is 26 rows by 26 columns. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Freq{
    private static final int ROWS = 26;
    private static final int COLS = 26;
    private static int[] [] alphabet = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(userInput.hasNextLine()) {
            line = userInput.nextLine();
            processLine(line);

        }
        printArray();

    }
    public static void processLine(String line) {
        line = line.toUpperCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < alphabet[i].length; j++) {
                for (int a = 0; a < line.length() - 1; a++) {
                    char firstLetter = line.charAt(a);
                    char secondLetter = line.charAt(a + 1);
                    if (firstLetter == secondLetter) {
                        alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void printArray() {
    for (int b = 0; b < alphabet.length; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < alphabet[b].length; c++){
            System.out.print(alphabet[b][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

However when I run my program and input "aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz"
this is what happens:

```
aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz
676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 676
```

I believe they are being added in the correct location, but why is my program adding 676 to the index and not just adding 1? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `processLine()` method does not make much sense.  First, you should only be iterating over the input string, and not the entire 2D array, i.e.:

```
public static void processLine(String line) {
    line = line.toUpperCase();
    for (int a=0; a < line.length() - 1; a++) {
        char firstLetter = line.charAt(a);
        char secondLetter = line.charAt(a + 1);
        if (firstLetter == secondLetter) {
            alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Second, your 2D array will only ever have entries on the diagonal, because you only ever make assignments where the two characters are the same for both dimensions.  So you could just use a 1D array:

```
private static int[] alphabet = new int[ROWS];

public static void processLine(String line) {
    line = line.toUpperCase();
    for (int a=0; a < line.length() - 1; a++) {
        char firstLetter = line.charAt(a);
        char secondLetter = line.charAt(a + 1);
        if (firstLetter == secondLetter) {
            alphabet[firstLetter - 65] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow i feel so dumb haha. Thank you for your help. Also, what if I had "aaaa", and I only wanted the first element in my array to be added once?

Comment: What should happen for `aaaabbbbaaaa`?  Are there two entries for `aa` or just one?

Comment: Just one, i'm just looking for one occurrence of the letter pair per line

Comment: You could use a map, but what would be logically wrong with just treating any positive count as being 1, and no count as being no match occurred?

Comment: I guess there wouldn't be anything wrong. I mean If i enter 2 lines of input: aabbaa                                                                                                             aabbaa                                                                                                                              I want the first element in my 2d array to be 2. And I'm not sure how I would do that. I can't set the element equal to 1. Because then if i have 10 lines with "aa" I will end up with only 1 in my first element, whereas I want 10.

Comment: I don't follow your logic now.  Maybe update your question with a visual of what you really want here.

Comment: Okay I'll create a new question. Thanks for your help

Comment: I added a new question if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it. :)

Answer (score 1):

What your are doing is that you are adding value from that position on matrix with 1 instead if you want 1 at that place just assign it
Replace this line

```
alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] += 1;
```

with this

```
alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] = 1;
```

or change your processLine method to this

```
 public static void processLine(String line) {
        line = line.toUpperCase();
            for (int a = 0; a < line.length() - 1; a++) {
                    char firstLetter = line.charAt(a);
                    char secondLetter = line.charAt(a + 1);
                    if (firstLetter == secondLetter) {
                        alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this answer your question